# Cartoon show in which a girl somehow went to another world where she fell from the sky but was caught by a horse or Pegasus

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, isekai

I remember watching this magical girls cartoon on YouTube. It was about a girl with a single dad. That girl had this necklace. One day, she somehow went to another world or an alternate universe. She was falling from the sky but then a horse or Pegasus caught her. that was the only scene I remember.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? And what colour was the girl's hair?

Comment: Also, was the animation hand-drawn or computer-generated?